# special character with chinese characters not substituted in python string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, chinese-locale

I cannot seem to substitute a '）' or a '（' without causing errors in other strings. '）' and '（' are special characters. Here are two strings "sample（志信达）.mbox" and "sample#宋安兴.mbox" . If I use re to substitute the characters,the chinese character suffers a substitution too. Here is the code in python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
source1='sample（志信达）.mbox'
source2='sample#宋安兴.mbox'
newname1=re.sub(r'[\(\);）（]','-',source1)
newname2=re.sub(r'[\(\);）（]','-',source2)
print source1,newname1
print source2,newname2
```

Here is the result:

```
sample（志信达）.mbox sample---志信达---.mbox
sample#宋安兴.mbox sample#宋?-兴.mbox
```

Notice that one of the characters is replaced with '?-'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search and replace utf-8 special characters in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054746/how-to-search-and-replace-utf-8-special-characters-in-python)

Comment: each chinese character is represented as 3 bytes in UTF-8, therefore it is replace by 3 '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use unicode literals (see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
source1 = u'sample（志信达）.mbox'
source2 = u'sample#宋安兴.mbox'
newname1 = re.sub(ur'[\(\);）（]','-',source1)
newname2 = re.sub(ur'[\(\);）（]','-',source2)
print source1,newname1
print source2,newname2
```

result:

```
sample（志信达）.mbox sample-志信达-.mbox
sample#宋安兴.mbox sample#宋安兴.mbox
```

Also, do not forget to save your `.py` file in UTF-8 (your IDE may do this automatically or you may have to manually change encoding depending on the text editor you use).

Comment: That's what I get: "...SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xef' in file ..."

Comment: Probably a problem with default encoding, did you put # -*- coding: utf -*- in the top?

Comment: @alfasin: You should save your file in UTF-8 and not forget the coding declaration on top.

Comment: Yes, I added the header `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6086504/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-07%20at%2010.25.55%20AM.png

Comment: @Selcuk see screenshot (the link) in my comment above

Comment: Works for me with PyCharm. I am not sure what is wrong with Sublime.

Comment: @selcuk your code doesn't achieve intended purpose which was to substitute these characters '\(\);）（' for '-'. I edited your answer so that it did achieve this purpose but it was not accepted.  Please change your code to this form: re.sub(u'[\(\);）（]','-',source1) with 'u' instead of 'r'. Perhaps you didn't notice that "（" is a special character?