# incorrect filename when saving an image

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with my script, and I'm trying to save it as `Algenblüte.png` but insead I `'Algenbl'$'\303\274''te.png'`
 one of the words in the list "**Algenblüte**" . However, if I used any other name like "**Abguss**" it saves it as Abguss.png with no problem.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    import os
    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
    filepath = 'name.txt'
    fonttype = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf'
    fntYU = ImageFont.truetype(fonttype, 150)
    i=0
    with open(filepath) as myfile:
        #for data in myfile and i in range(2):
        #for data in myfile:
         for index, data in enumerate(myfile):
             print (data)
             if index == 3:
                break

             if (len(data)) <= 12:
                img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), color = (255, 255, 255))
                fnt = ImageFont.truetype(fonttype, 550)
                d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
                d.text((600,700), data, font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))
                img.save(data.replace('\n', '')+".png")
```

Comment: it might be useful to mention operating system and filesystem

Comment: I assume this is due to the encoding of the `ü` character?

Comment: Yes, you're correct

Answer (score 0):

The file `name.txt` might have a different encoding. Try using the `encode` string function to convert the file name to `utf-8` before calling `save`.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem origin**

Your problem is linked to the German **"Ü"** which is not a **standard** string value. IT will be encoded as such.

**Small test**

Try the usual German conversion and use `algenbluete.png` and you should not have the problem.

**Fast solution**

You have very few such files, then **rename them manually**.

It is dull, I know,  but in my humble experience a lot of python libraries hate German, Czech, French, etc. special characters.

**Quick and dirty solution**

The amount of German special characters are limited `[ä, ü, ö, ß]`:

1. Use [this code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054746/how-to-search-and-replace-utf-8-special-characters-in-python) as an inspiration
2. Build a (nested) loop to replace the values